# tkinter argument passing between two functions

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
x1=StringVar()
y=IntVar()

def hello(z):
    print z

def temp():
    root1=Tk()
    x1.set("hello world")
    Entry(root1,textvariable=x1).pack()
    Button(root1,text="try me",command=(lambda :hello (x1.get()))).pack()

    root1.mainloop()



Button(root,text="enter the new window",command=temp).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

iam new to tkinter.i am struck with argument passing between functions in tkinter

in the above code when try me button is clicked i want the text entered in the entry box to be passed to the function but instead every time hello world is printing.

please tell me way to get text from entry and that text must be passed on to the function
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing x1.get() to hello() that's why every time `hello world` is printed. Instead of that, fetch the current `Entry` text and pass it to hello(). To fetch the current `Entry` text, use the `get` method of `Entry Widget`

Modify your code as shown below:

```
e = Entry(root1,textvariable=x1)
e.pack();
Button(root1,text="try me",command=(lambda :hello (e.get()))).pack()
```

Comment: i am using python 2.7 and this is not working iam getting an error.iam pasting the error below.                                                               Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Python27/project/trailaaa.py", line 13, in <lambda>
    Button(root1,text="try me",command=(lambda :hello (e.get()))).pack()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: This code is tested and working fine on Python 2.7.9 (Windows)

Comment: Did you change your code as mentioned in Answer? `e = Entry(root1,textvariable=x1)`

Comment: now it worked when i chaged  initially i wrote e=Entry(root1,textvariable=x1).pack(). when i changed it worked. thanks a lot